# How to set sqlite3 model to multi-threads which is installed by python3?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, sqlite

Python 3 already has SQLite 3 installed, but its mode is serialized. How can I use multithreads mode?

Comment: Looks like it defaults that way already (The check_same_thread to the connect method is true by default).

Comment: No, the default mode is serialized. And set check_same_thread to False, it can share connection, but it seems to get data from sql in queue.

Comment: Like in C or C++, it can be set use sqlite3_config(SQLITE_CONFIG_MULTITHREAD), but how can I do that in python?

Comment: Setting that argument to false would turn on serialized mode, unless the python documentation is using the opposite terminology as https://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html (I can't recommend using serialized mode. One connection object per thread to the same database, aka multithreaded mode, is saner and less error prone)

Comment: Yes, so I want to change it to multithreads mode, but how to do that in python?

Comment: Once again, that's the default behavior.